# custom browser url with WCF4 on IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wcf-rest

I'm using WCF 4 on IIS 7.5 and want to eliminate the default .svc extension from the URL of all my Restful services.

For Example :

`I have the browser URL as  http://localhost:6025/Services/Company.svc/`

But, the required URL is `http://localhost:6025/Company`

Please help me if you have solution on that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need either a .svc file or a .svc URL under .NET 4.  Instead, you can register services via routing integration, as shown at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358760(v=vs.100).aspx.